# How to transfer multiple files from sub directories to a single path folder using python?

Tags: python, pandas, directory, glob, shutil

I have a list of names(all unique) of Wav files-

```
2003211085_2003211078_ffc0d543799a2984c60c581d.wav
2003214817_2003214800_92720fb19bf9216c2f160733.wav
2003233142_2003233136_8c42d206701830dff6032d41.wav
2003256235_2003256218_4e71bf77b0ffb907990d2e30.wav
2003276239_2003276196_dad6aff70f37817fcd75ffb8.wav
2003352182_2003352170_b1f2990d5f867408cc39c445.wav
```

There is a directory called \019\Recordings where all of these files are located under various subfolders.
I want to write a python app that pulls these wav files based on their unique name from all these subfolders and places them into a single target folder.

Im new to python and tried using -

```
import glob, os
import shutil

target_list_of_wav_names = ["2003211085_2003211078_ffc0d543799a2984c60c581d.wav",
"2003214817_2003214800_92720fb19bf9216c2f160733.wav",
"2003233142_2003233136_8c42d206701830dff6032d41.wav"
"2003352182_2003352170_b1f2990d5f867408cc39c445.wav"]

for file in glob.glob('//19/Recordings*.wav', recursive=True):
    print(file)
    if file in target_list_of_wav_names:
        shutil.move(file, "C:/Users/ivd/Desktop/autotranscribe"+file)
```

But the files do not reflect in the target folder

How can i fix this?

Comment: You can just play around a bit with "copy" and "copy2" in "shutil" module to understand how they should be called to do the desired copying.

Comment: add / to the end of "C:/Users/ivd/Desktop/autotranscribe/"

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob, os
import shutil

target_list_of_wav_names = ['example_wav1.wav','example_wav2.wav',...... etc]

for file in glob.glob('/019/Recordings/*.wav', recursive=True):
    print(file)
    if file in target_list_of_wav_names:
        shutil.move(file, "/mydir/"+file)
```

Comment: Question -  where would i be mentioning the source folder here of  \019\Recordings? and how will it know i am looking for the specific wav files based on the name i mentioned and not just all * wavs.

Comment: Edited my answer with path example,not sure if i undertand your filestructure.

Comment: ok let me explain with an example - let us say you have the file names of recordings(wavs) and want to pull them from a path. this path has multiple subfolder. so you cant really manually look through each subfolder to pull each wav. So now in order to automate this script, i want to pull only these specific filenames from the source folder, which will take these specific wavs and place them in a target folder. in your script, where can i mention the specific names of .wavs i am trying to pull?

Comment: do you mean target_list_of_wav_names = [wav1.wav,wav2.wav,....etc]

Comment: I tested the script. it ran however, the wav files from the destination folder /019/Recordings did not transfer to the target folder of /mydir/

Comment: I supose you changed the names example_wav1.wav

Comment: yes i did. my final script was import glob, os
import shutil

target_list_of_wav_names = ["2003211085_2003211078_ffc0d543799a2984c60c581d.wav",
"2003214817_2003214800_92720fb19bf9216c2f160733.wav",
"2003233142_2003233136_8c42d206701830dff6032d41.wav"
"2003352182_2003352170_b1f2990d5f867408cc39c445.wav"]

for file in glob.glob('//019/Recordings*.wav', recursive=True):
    print(file)
    if file in target_list_of_wav_names:
        shutil.move(file, "C:/Users/ivd/Desktop/autotranscribe"+file)

Comment: ive edited my script in the question so u can see it clearer

Comment: I added autotranscribe/  and ran it but unfortunately i still dont see those files in the target directory

Answer (score 1):

glob is just a utility to find files based on a wildcard. It returns the string of the files that match your query.

So you'll still need to actually move the file with another function.

you could use `os.rename` or `shutil.move` to move it

```
for file in glob.glob("*.wav"):
    os.rename(file, f'destinationfolder/{file}')
```

Comment: i have a rookie question, how would this pick up the files by the specific file names i have? i dont want it to pick up all wav files from source directory  \019\Recordings. i only want it to pick up the specific ones i have as listed above and then transfer those files to a target folder

Comment: check out this site on how to use glob https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/. So you'll want to change the pattern used in the argument